# py2exe and active_directory producing "ImportError: cannot import name adsi" once EXE is run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, active-directory, py2exe, importerror

When running an EXE compiled by py2exe it fails with the error:

```
  File "AccessADData.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "active_directory.pyc", line 105, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name adsi
```

Running it as just a python script produces no errors at all. I have all the required DLLs. I belive the root of the problem is with [tim golden's active_directory](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/ad_cookbook.html).

Any suggestions on alternate ways to compile or a solution for this Error would be much appreciated?